# Can't access gmail account with Python 3 "SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed"

Tags: python, email, smtp

Hi I hope you can help me :)

I want to access my gmail account with python to automate sending emails. I bought the email through Wix with the website editor and domain name as well.

I turned the less secure app on the email account and I still get error message  "SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed":

**My code** :

```
conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
conn.starttls()
conn.ehlo() 
conn.login('myemail', 'mypassword')
```

Error : SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

**I tried these two solutions but I keep having the same error:**

1)

```
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
s.ehlo()
s.login('myemail', 'mypassword')
```

2. 

```
import smtplib, ssl
conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
conn.starttls(context=context)
conn.ehlo() 
conn.login('myemail', 'mypassword')
```

I hope you can help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

### python smtplib debugging (Connection unexpectedly closed)

1. Can you get SMTP server greeting messages using telnet?
   Is it pyhon/smtplib only problem?
   Your comp may be firewalle-out from gmail access.

   ```
   telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
   ```
2. Turn on smtp session tracing
   smtplib.set_debuglevel(2)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel